# Unable to run Jmeter.bat

Tags: java, jmeter

I'm trying to use Jmeter but am coming across an issue when I try and run it using the Jmeter.bat file.

It's spits out the following error:

```
'java -version 2>&1 | findstr /i "version"' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
Not able to find Java executable or version. Please check your Java installation.
errorlevel=2
Press any key to continue . . .
```

I've tried googling this and lots of posts mention that this error is usually down to the environment variables not being set correctly, but I'm fairly sure they are as if I type java or javac into the command prompt I get a response.

I've got them set as follows:

- JAVA_HOME : C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25
- JDK_HOME  : %JAVA_HOME%
- JRE_HOME  : %JAVA_HOME%\jre
- CLASSPATH : .;%JAVA_HOME%\lib;%JAVA_HOME%\jre\lib
- PATH      : your-unique-entries;%JAVA_HOME%\bin

I tried taking the string it's complaining about and pasted that into the command prompt by itself and it ran fine:

```
C:\Windows\System32>java -version 2>&1 | findstr /i "version"
java version "1.8.0_25"
```

So why is it throwing the error when running the batch file but not if I paste it in manually? The batch file is located in a folder in my C drive and I'm running by right clicking and selecting 'Run as Administrator'. If I just double click the .bat file I get the error:

```
Windows cannot find 'C:\apache-jmeter-2.13_src\bin\jmeter.bat'. Make sure you typed the name correctly, and then try again
```

Is the above error related or is that a separate permissions issue?

Thanks for any help

Comment: are you able to run 'java -version' via command line?

Comment: oh sorry just see in your answer, locate the bin directory and try: "java -jar ApacheJMeter.jar"

Comment: Thanks HRgiger. Running that opens what appears to be the JMeter tool.  Is this the correct way to launch the application? Or is that some kind of workaround that proves the error lies somewhere else?

Comment: No its not actually, bat file does version check and sets additional java arguments something like heap size enabling dump etc... But I always use java way. So at least we know that problem with bat permission or environment. Try to copy apache folder into your desktop and try again if you want bat execution

Answer (score 4):

From command Prompt go to bin folder of apache jmeter and type following command:
**C:\apache-jmeter-3.0\bin>** java -jar ApacheJmeter.jar

Answer (score -1):

I also faced similar problem when I extracted the JMeter in C. In my case, i don't have admin rights. I assume it is related to some permission issue. So better copy to D: and then check.

Copy C:\apache-jmeter-2.13_src folder to other drive (D:) or download JMeter and extract in D drive and run the batch file.

Comment: Why? Could you possibly expand on why this would solve OP's problem?

Comment: I also faced similar problem when I extracted the JMeter in C. In my case, i don't have admin rights. I assume it is related to some permission issue. So better copy to D: and then check.

Comment: Then your answer should say all of that. The way it is written, your answer does not help understand what the problem could be.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Updated the answer.